# Focus input element and show keyboard in Android WebView on load

Tags: android, webview, focus

I have problem with Android `WebView`.
I want to focus input element and show `keyboard` on page load without any user actions. Setting input element focus works fine, but keyboard isn't showing. If I make some button in `HTML` with same action to set focus then keyboard will appear.

Is this even doable to focus input element in WebView and show keyboard on page load?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You must force open the keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
```

You should also make sure that your WebView has focus and field of content is tagged with:

```
type="number"
```

Comment: ! This only works for cases with "qwerty" input, will not open the numeric keypad.